# Is it possible to reverse proxy to native running applications from a containerized Nginx in K3S?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, containers, reverse-proxy, k3s

On my server I run some applications directly on the host. In parallel I have a single-node K3S that also contains a few applications. To be able to manage the traffic routing and HTTPS certificates to the individual services in a central place I want to use Nginx. In the cluster runs a traefik ingress controller which I use for the routing in this context.

To be able to reverse proxy to each application, no matter if it runs directly on the host or in a container in K3S, Nginx must be able to reach the applications locally, no matter where it runs (without the traffic leaving the server). E.g. proxy `myservice.mydomain.com`  to `localhost:8080` from Nginx should end up on the webserver of a nativly running application and `myservice2.mydomain.com`  to the webserver of a container in K3S.

Now, is this possible if the Nginx runs in the K3S cluster or do I have to install it directly on the host machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Nginx that way yes you can do it.

keeping Nginx in front of Host and K3S also.

You can expose your service as NodePort from K3s and while local servie that you will be running on Host machine will be also running on one Port.

in this Nginx will forward the traffic like

```
Nginx -> Port-(8080) MachineIp: 8080 -> Application on K3s
               |
         Port-(3000) MachineIp: 3000 -> Application running on Host
```

Example : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/